# Help me with lining up my 2012 Honda Pilot crankshaft and camshaft

Tags: honda, timing-belt, camshaft, crankshaft, pilot

I actually attempted rotating the crankshaft counter clockwise to line the crank, and cams up, I’m reaching a stopping point both ways, should I remove the belt?

Answer (score 1):

If the front cam and crankshaft are in alignment with the timing marks and the rear cam is out, you'll have to remove the timing belt in order to get it aligned, **so yes, remove the belt**. Just don't turn the crankshaft with the belt off. I mean, if you need to tweak the crank a little so it is aligned with the timing mark, then it's all good. A few degrees movement in either direction is not going to hurt anything. Also remember to re-pin the hydraulic tensioner. It'll make life easier for you to get everything back together.